# Why is it a bad habit to parse and evaluate a string code (in R)?

Tags: r, parsing, expression, eval

I've been told that it is a bad habit to parse and evaluate a character string

```
to_run = "for (i in 1:10){print(i);print('Hello World!')}"

eval(parse(text=to_run))
```

**Why is it a bad habit?**

It seems to me to be quite a flexible way of programming as we can construct our code in a iterative manner by pasting character strings together. For example it allows to easily deal with objects of various dimensions for example.

```
if (length(dim(my.array)) == 2){to_run = "A = my.array[1,]"}
if (length(dim(my.array)) == 3){to_run = "A = my.array[1,,]"}
eval(parse(text=to_run))
```

Comment: Among other things, don't you think that this makes your code less flexible and less reusable in the long run?

Comment: See, also, [dangers of eval(parse())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-modifying code is much more difficult to understand than to write. The example you gave has a perfectly valid R equivalent:

```
if (length(dim(my.array)) == 2) {
  A = my.array[1,]
} else if (length(dim(my.array)) == 3)
  A = my.array[1,,]
```

Comment: Ok, good point. It makes the code more complex to read and understand.